# How to open an API URL in Swagger

Tags: api, swagger

I have a URL say (https://example.net/api) and I need to see the endpoints associated with this URL in Swagger to perform API calls.

I tried options like (https://example.net/api/swagger.json) and (https://example.net/api/swagger.yaml) in Swagger Hub and Inspector as well but no luck. Instead I'm getting request terminated error.

Can anyone help me out with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to open the swagger page, or on the swagger page open up a specific url? Please update your question with more information.

Comment: If you mean default swagger specification endpoint, it's depends on used doc generator and configs. For example, Swashbuckle binds endpoint to /swagger/v1/swagger.json by default, but this endpoint may be changed easily by the middleware configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by "check the endpoints in Swagger against this address"? Send HTTP requests to the API? Export the OpenAPI YAML/JSON definition file? Something else?

Comment: I am looking to open that particular URL on the swagger page and then look into what are the endpoints associated with it. Then I need to send API calls to validate CRUD operations. But I have no clue where could I parse this URL.

Comment: Have you tried https://example.net/swagger/index.html